# How to save and update points in a share preferences

Tags: java, android

I have my **BoostPoints** activity for users to boost points by watching rewarded video ads, Yes points they add up when the user is watching ads, the problem now is, when i close the activity or app and reopen it the points go back to zero. For example the user watched ads and gained 100 points, when the user closes the activity or app without using these points and open it again later, the points disappear and go back to zero. I want the points to be available even if the user closes the app and open it later they should see their points where they left.

I tried this code in my `onCreate();`

```
//Save Coins
    SharedPreferences saveCoins = this.getSharedPreferences("mySaverCoins", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    pointsAmount = saveCoins.getInt("C",0);
```

When i run my app with this code it doesnt save my coins, it goes back to zero everytime i start it.

I tried also to add this line in `onCreate();

```
pointsAvailable.setText("C"+pointsAmount);
```

But my activity crashes because of this line

My full **java.class** looks like this

```
public class BoostPoints extends AppCompatActivity  implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

public int pointsAmount = 0;

private RewardedVideoAd mAd;
Button freePoints;
TextView pointsAvailable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_boost_points);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();


    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

    mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    LoadRewardedVideoAd();
    mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

    freePoints=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFreePoints);


    //Save Coins
    SharedPreferences saveCoins = this.getSharedPreferences("mySaverCoins", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    pointsAmount = saveCoins.getInt("C",0);


    //Update Coins
    pointsAvailable.setText("C"+pointsAmount); //This line crashes my activity

    //Show points available
    pointsAvailable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointsAvailable);

}


public void FreePoints(View view) {
    if (mAd.isLoaded()){
        mAd.show();

    }
}

private void LoadRewardedVideoAd()
{
    if (!mAd.isLoaded()){
        mAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    pointsAmount = pointsAmount +10;
    pointsAvailable.setText("C"+pointsAmount);
}

}
```

what could be the problem with my code

Comment: Code for saving points to the pref?

Comment: yes sir thats what i want

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `int` to `String` using

```
pointsAvailable.setText("C"+String.valueOf(pointsAmount));
```

And to save the points, you need to store them in the `SharedPreferences` in `onRewarded`:

```
saveCoins.edit().putInt("C",pointsAmount).commit()
```